# ckeditor gets shown only once in a foreach statement asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor

I am working on a blog and I want users to be able to comment on blogs with some extra mark up from ckeditor. So I have made a foreach statement to show all the comments and a textarea field with ckeditor per blog post. Now the strange thing is all works fine but the ckeditor works only with the first blog while the textareas are visible at all blogs.

**This is the error the webinspector shows**

> Uncaught The editor instance "editor1" is already attached to the provided element.

**here is my view**

```
 IEnumerable<Portfolio.Models.Messages>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/Comments.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Blog.css" />

@*Shows the blog posts that are posted to the database*@
@foreach (var messages in Model)
{
    <div class="jumbotron opacity_container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    @*Gets the title of the blog post*@
                    <h2 class="panel-title">
                     @messages.Title
                    </h2>
                    @messages.WhenCreated
                </div>    
                @*Gets the body of the blog post and decodes the html of the 
                 ckeditor*@
                <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(messages.Body))
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @*this button gets the id from the database of the Message table 
          this helps to prevent that all the comments from all blogs gets 
          shown and thusshows only the comments that belong to the blog in 
          question*@

          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="@messages.MessagesId" 
          onclick="ShowComments(this.id)">
          Show Comments
          </button>

        @*this is the container where al the comments are placed in and 
        where you can post comments. The comments are placed in the Comment 
        partial view*@

        <div class="hidden" id="Comm@(messages.MessagesId)">
        @Html.Partial("_Comment")

        @*this button gets the id from the database of the Message table 
        this helps to prevent that all the comments from all blogs gets 
        hidden and thushides only the comments that belong to the blog in 
        question*@

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="@messages.MessagesId"
            onclick="HideComments(this.id)">
            Hide Comments
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

> The partialview is called in the div with the classname hidden.

**this is my partial view**

```
@model IEnumerable<Portfolio.Models.Messages>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Blog.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="CommentContainer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Post Comment</h3>
        @*The form to post comments*@
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Messages"))
            {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Comment</label>
                @Html.TextArea("editor1", htmlAttributes: 
                new { name = "editor1", 
                id = "editor1", rows = "10", cols = "180" })
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
                 id="PostButton">Post Comment
                </button>
            } 

        @*CKEditor script*@
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        </script>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @*Places al the comments and decodes the html from the 
                    ckeditor*@
                    @foreach(var messages in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="well" id="CommentBox">                       
                           @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
                           (messages.Body))
                       </div>
                    }
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The ckeditor is placed inside the partial view that is placed inside the foreach loop. So what I dont get is why is the taxtarea is visible at all posts but the ckeditor not, while they are both inside the same foreach statement.

Comment: All your CKEditors have the same ID (editor1), don't they? Make sure to generate a unique ID for each of them

Comment: Thnx for the comment it was indeed the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gyum Fox said all the CkEditors had the same id and that doesn't work because a id should be unique.